# How to merge OpenVPN client app with another android app?

Tags: java, android, vpn, openvpn

I need to connect my application to different servers on my network using openvpn protocol.

All works using OpenVPN Connect or OpenVPN for Android apps ([link](http://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/)).

Now I would like to integrate OpenVPN app with mine so that everything gets automated.

(i.e)The user doesn't have to install an additional app and user doesn't have to configure it all by himself.

Is it possible ?

Any help on app integration will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

It sound a lot like you want to build your own VPN provider app. That is certainly possible.
You can control OpenVPN for Android via an API or build an app on top of it. Just make sure you respect the license of ics-openvpn (see README for details). If in doubt contact the author of the app.